# insert value into one to one mapping annotation using ebeans or hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, ebean

Hi I am trying to implement ebeans one-to-one mapping with ebeans with  user and user_profile details. I have done annotation marking  with each key but not able to insert the value at run time.

UserProfile.java

```
@Entity
public class UserProfile extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long userProfileId;

    public String empId;
    public String name;
    public String emailId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "email")
    public User user;

    //inserting filled form into database
    public static Long create(UserProfile userProfile)
    {
        //save leave into database
        userProfile.save();
        return userProfile.serial_id;
    }
```

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static Finder<String, User> find = new Finder<String, User>(String.class, User.class);


    @Id
    public String email;
    public String name;
    public String password;
    public String permission;
    public int userProfileId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    public UserProfile profile;

    public User(long id,String email, String name, String password,String permission,
                int user_id) {
        //this.id=id;
       this.email = email;
       this.name = name;
       this.password = password;
       this.permission = permission;
       this.user_id = user_id;
    }
```

I want to insert userprofile table's userprofile_id into user's userProfileId.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```java
@Entity
public class UserProfile extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long userProfileId;

    public String empId;
    public String name;    

    @OneToOne
    public User user;

    //inserting filled form into database
    public static Long create(UserProfile userProfile)
    {
        //save leave into database
        userProfile.save();
        return userProfile.serial_id;
    }
```

```java
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static Finder<String, User> find = new Finder<String, User>(String.class, User.class);


    @Id
    public String email;
    public String name;
    public String password;
    public String permission;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    public UserProfile profile;

    public User(long id,String email, String name, String password,String permission,
                int user_id, UserProfile profileIn) {
        //this.id=id;
       this.email = email;
       this.name = name;
       this.password = password;
       this.permission = permission;
       this.user_id = user_id;
       this.profile = profileIn;
    }
```

The difference is that you don't need `emailId` in `UserProfile` entity and `userProfileId` in `User` entity. Simply use the entity instance and hibernate will do its job. If you at all need to expose the `userProfileId` in `User` entity to allow services to access just the id then amend `User` class with following changes:

```java
@Column(name = "profileId", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long profileId;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.LAZY, nullable = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "profileId")
private UserProfile profile;
```

Last but not the least please do not expose the properties like you have done in your classes. Make them private and implement getter/setter methods.

Comment: I want when ever user insert into userprofile table  userprofile id is autotomcatically inserted into user. does it possible ??

Comment: Yes its possible. Once you persists UserProfile entity simply call entityManager.refresh() on your User entity instance and you will get updated user instance with profile id. If thats the case then I would prefer removing UserProfile from User entity constructor, add User as constructor parameter for UserProfile class and add a getter method for UserProfile in User class. Please do not forget to vote for my answer if it helps you in any way possible. Thanks!

Comment: while inserting I am getting an error 'ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Column 'profileId' cannot be null]' can you help me out.

Comment: If you are saving User without UserProfile then please remove the nullable constraint from profile and profileId fields. Also make sure that NULL constraint is removed from database table.

Comment: I am not able to insert the value .can you give me the code.